# Ownership of QString with QTextStream

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtextstream

I am trying to use `QTextStream` to read from a `QString`. Since the constructor has the following signature:

```
    QTextStream(QString *string, QIODevice::OpenMode openMode = QIODevice::ReadWrite)
```

(see [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html))

Since the constructor is passed a raw pointer, I wonder if the `QTextStream` takes ownership of the `QString` or if I have to manage it in my code to ensure that the `QString` object is deleted after the `QTextStream` object.

I haven't found any information on this neither in the documentation nor on search engines (e.g. google, duckduckgo). All examples I have found show a `QString` and a `QTextStream` that have the same lifetime (local variables in the same function), so I am not sure what happens if the two objects have different lifetimes.

Comment: I haven't used `QTextStream` using this particular constructor. However, I think that the `QTextStream ` object merely uses the `QString` to read from or write to. It does not take ownership of the `QString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QTextStream` doesn't take the ownership of the `QString`.

In fact you can write a function like this:

```
void test()
{
    QString s;
    QTextStream ts(&s);
    ///.....
}
```

If the `QTextStream` takes the ownership, in this case the `QString` would be deleted two times, and there would be a runtime error. But this code is correct, so the `QTextStream` doesn't take the ownership

Answer (score 3):

If the documentation doesn't *specifically* state that the `QTextStream` object takes ownership, it's fairly safe to assume that it doesn't.  It would be a pretty nasty omission otherwise.

But if you don't trust the documentation to inform you, you have two recourses: read the [source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/io/qtextstream.cpp) or test the behaviour in code.

As it turns out, `QTextStream` doesn't take ownership and will never attempt to delete the `QString*`.  This raises the question as to why the parameter isn't declared as `const QString*`, but that's a whole other question.

I encourage you to write a unit test if you want a 100% guarantee.  While extremely unlikely (this isn't PHP after all), it's just possible that the behaviour will change in a later version.

Comment: The reason it's not `const` is because `QTextStream` can write into it as well: `stream << 2; //the string will now contain "2"`.

Comment: "This raises the question as to why the parameter isn't declared as const QString*" - because you may want to write to it.

Comment: Ahh of course.  Didn't realize it was a read-write container.  Thanks.